# Is it appropriate to use extension methods on types that you own?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have the following classes in my solution with the `Request` class being allowed to create `Response` instances:

```
public class Request
{
    public Guid Id {get;} 

    public int UserId {get;}

    public string SomeInfo {get;}

    public Request(Guid id, int userId, string someInfo)
    {
        Id = id;
        UserId = userId;
        SomeInfo = someInfo;
    }

    public Response GetResponse(string content)
    {
        return new Response(requestId, content);
    }
}

public class Response
{
    public Guid Id {get;}

    public Guid RequestId {get;}

    public string Content {get;}

    public Response(Guid requestId, string content)
    {
         Id = Guid.NewGuid();
         RequestId = requestId;
         Content = content;
    }
}
```

Let's say I remove the `GetResponse` method and move its code into an extension method, like this:

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
     public static Response GetResponse(this Request request, string content)
     {
           return new Response(request.Id, content);
     }
}
```

Is it an appropriate use of the extension methods? I understand the need of those in the context where you do not have access to the type. But does that make sense to use an extension method on a type I do own?

Comment: Sure. If you change the type itself it's part of it. An extension can be ignored if you don't need it or if it doesn't make sense in a specific context.

Comment: Your scenario is about classes but the clear case is when the type is an interface and not a class, yes, it is very appropriate.  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my mind (though this question is fairly opinion-based) doing this makes sense in one scenario:

- `GetResponse` needs to live in a different assembly than `Response` for some reason (and there are valid ones)

Otherwise you can just use a `partial` class if you want the code files separate for some reason.

Comment: Just found the guideline on the asp git project: "The general rule is: if a regular static method would suffice, avoid extension methods." https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Engineering-guidelines